# How to solve page not found 404 - python django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have created an app which has the index.html which is the main page and when I run "py manage.py runserver" command it opens the index page. Then I created another app for home page and added urls, created views and everything as far as I know. But when I click "home" it navigates to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/home.html" and says "Page not found(404)" and "'home.html' could not be found" I will paste my code below

**webapp\settings.py:**

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tbs',
    'tbs_home'
]
```

**webapp\urls.py:**
urlpatterns = [

```html
path('', include('tbs.urls')),
    path('tbs_home', include('tbs_home.urls')), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    
]
```

**tbs_home\urls.py:**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('home',views.home, name='home') 
]
```

**tbs_home\views.py:**

```html
def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**templates\home.html:**

```html
{% extends 'index.html' %}
 {% load static%}

 {% block content%}

<h1 style = "font-family:Georgia;font:40px;font-style:normal;">Hi! {{name}}</h1>
<form action="add" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st num : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates\index.html:**

This is the part where "home.html" link is given in "index.html" page

```html
<div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1">
<ul>
 <li class="active"><a href="{% static 'home.html' %}">Home</a></li>
```

I think I've provided the necessary code snippets, thank you for your help in advance. I should be able to navigate to home page from index page when I click the home button.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the static tag with the url tag

```
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'tbs_home:home' %}">Home</a></li>
```

The part in front the ':' tells django which app to look into and the part after the ':' says which url to use. The `static` tag points it to your staticfiles directory which you don't want

In the tbs_home\urls.py, add the app_name

```
app_name = 'tbh_home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('home',views.home, name='home') 
]
```

And in the webapp\urls.py, add a trailing backslash to the url like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tbs_home/', include('tbs_home.urls')), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Comment: I receive this error "NoReverseMatch at /
'tbs_home' is not a registered namespace" now, thanks @leelum1

Comment: add app_name = 'tbs_home' in tbs_home urls.py

Comment: tbs_home/urls.py: urlpatterns = [
    
    path('home',views.home, name='home'), 
    
]      This is present url that I have where should I change the app_name to 'tbs_home' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
in tbs_home\urls.py:
```

change that to :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/',views.home, name='home'),# adding comma is important
]
```

```
webapp\urls.py: urlpatterns = [path('', include('tbs.urls')),
    path('tbs_home/', include('tbs_home.urls')), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # adding comma is important
    
]
```

Change installed apps to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: if it helps then kindly upvote and if there is an issue pls comment

Comment: Thanks @Divyeesh, I'm still getting an error saying "NoReverseMatch at /
'tbs_home' is not a registered namespace"

Comment: Yeah I tried, but getting an error message "NoReverseMatch at / 'tbs_home' is not a registered namespace"

Comment: This was the final possible reason of problem